# UberUploadCropper progressbar/spinner not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, upload

I'm using UberUploadCropper for my project its working well but only one issue Upload progress bar or upload spinner is not showing.

Reference:- http://trentrichardson.com/2011/12/20/uberuploadcropper-v2-upload-crop-no-flash/

The following code I have used in my project

https://github.com/trentrichardson/UberUploadCropper/blob/master/example-advanced/index.php

Thanks!